# arithemetic on multiple return values lua

Tags: lua

Is it possible to perform arithmetic on multiple values in Lua.
I am using Lua for windows 5.1.4.

Currently I have to put the multiple values into a table and then unpack them, and I would like to be able to skip that step.

Is it possible.

Here is what I currently have:

```
function numsToStr(...)
    local nums = {}
    for i,v in ipairs({...}) do
         nums[i] = v + string.byte('A') - 1
    end
    return string.char(unpack(nums))
end
```

What I want is to be able to do this

```
function numsToStr(...)
   return string.char(...+string.byte('A')-1)
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do arithmetic on multiple values in Lua.

Comment: Is there some other sort of construct that would do something similar, or would this be the best way to do it (efficiency,size of code wise) ?

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to do "directly", but you can implement "map" function, similar to what you've done. Some relevant resources: [Short anonymous functions](http://lua-users.org/wiki/ShortAnonymousFunctions), [thread on Perl-like map/grep functions](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2008-08/msg00190.html), and [map and other functions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Lua_Functional_Programming/Functions). Also take a look at [list comprehensions in Penlight](http://stevedonovan.github.io/Penlight/api/modules/pl.comprehension.html).

Comment: there has [lua-vararg](https://github.com/moteus/lua-vararg) library that already do that. `return va.map(dowork, ...)`